# this query error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT INDEX_ITEM_ID,     INDEX_ITEM_CLASS,     INDEX_ITEM_NAME,        CE_NROOPE,     CE_PRODUCTO,  CE_OPE_DIVISA, CE_OPE_IMPORTE, CE_ESTADO, CE_FECHALTA, CE_FECHACANC, CE_CLI_NOMBRE, CE_CLI_TIPODOC, CE_CLI_NRODOC, CE_DESTINO, CE_TIPOLOGIA, CE_FECHA, CE_ESTADO_DOC, CE_WORKSTEP,  CE_OBSERVACION, CE_ATRIBUTO, CE_ENVRECIB, CE_INDICE, CE_SUBINDICE, CE_NRO_SUBINDICE, CE_PARA_BROWSER, DEP_TIFNAME, DEP_VOLUMEN, OJ_NROOFI, N_IMAGENES,     D_ARCHIVO,     CE_PREPARADOR,     N_ID_DOC, CE_DIGITALIZADOR, CE_OPERADOR ,    CE_REGIONAL,     CE_TIPO_DOC,     CE_NRODOC,     CE_OPE_TIPO,     CE_OPE_IMPORTE_OLD,     RH_LEGAJO,     RH_TIPO_DOC,     FECHA_INGRESO,     OJ_AMPARO_ID,     OJ_ATRIBUTO,     OJ_OBSERVACION,     OJ_ESTADO_DOC,     OJ_TIPOOFI,     OJ_TIPODOC,     OJ_ESTADO,     OJ_PAGDEP,     OJ_NRO_OFI,     CE_LIQUIDADOR,     CE_OFICIAL_GESTION,     CE_AUT_LIQUIDACION,     CE_AUT_ANALISIS,     CE_BANDEJA,     FORM_NOMBRE,     CE_DATOS_GESTION,     CE_DATOS_LIQUID,     N_IMAGENES_SCAN,     CE_COD_CONCEPTO,     CE_BOLETO_COMPRA,     CE_FACTURA,     CE_DDJJ_4443,     CE_PE,     CE_MENS_GRUPO,     CE_COD_CONCEPTO2,     CE_PRIORIDAD,     CE_DOCRESPALDO,     CE_BOLETO_VENTA,     CE_CONT_PREST,     CE_DOC_TRANSP,     CE_DESP_PLAZA,     CE_COMA_4605,     CE_LIQ_PAGO,     CE_GUIA_COUR,     CE_INF_CP,     CE_IMP_GAN,     CE_ORDCOMP,     CE_COMA_3602,     CE_CONST_ID,     CE_FONDOS_DISP,     CE_COMA_4860,     CE_FECHA_NO_DISTRIBUCION,     CE_ENTRADA_BANDEJA,     CE_DEUDAS_SAPP,     CE_FACTURA_IMPO,     CE_NOTA_CRED,     CE_DDJJ_43170,     CE_CARTA_EXPO,     CE_FACT_EBC,     CE_FAC_E_CONT_ARR,     CE_COMP_DESEMBOLSO,     CE_COMP_GASTOS,     CE_COMP_APORTE,     CE_GAR_EJECUTADA,     CE_FOT_PAGO,     CE_FOT_ESCRIT_TRAS,     CE_DOC_RESP_GASTO ,    CE_FOT_INTIM_EJEC,     TIPO_LOTE,     CE_PRESCAN_OBS,     CE_PRESCAN_COMENT,     CE_NRO_CAJA,     CE_DESP_PLAZA_ANSEPA,     CE_CARTA_CONNROOPE,     CE_NOTACRED_EXPO,     CE_DISC_GO,     CE_DATOS_IMPO,     CE_COMP_LIQ_CIA_ASEG,     CE_FAC_PROV_EXT,     CE_COMP_INS_ORG_OF,     CE_RECLAMO_EXT ,    CE_COMP_GAR ,    CE_CERT_SSN,     CE_DISCSEG_DESPACHO,     CE_DISCSEG_FACTURA,     CE_DISCSEG_PE ,    CE_DISCSEG_CARTAAP,     CE_DISCSEG_PRORROGA,     CE_DISCSEG_PTO56,     CE_DISCSEG_NOTAAP,     CE_DISCSEG_CC_BOLETO,     CE_DISCSEG_CC_NOTA,     CE_DISCSEG_DDJJ3473,     CE_DISCSEG_CC_PE,     CE_DISCSEG_CC_FAC,     CE_DISCSEG_CT_PE,     CE_DISCSEG_CT_NOCRED ,    CE_DISCSEG_CT_NOTAAP ,    CE_DISCSEG_CT4025_PE,     CE_DISCSEG_CT4025FAC,     CE_DISCSEG_COM_3602 ,    CE_DISCPD_PRESTMONEX ,    CE_DISCPD_PAGARE ,    CE_DISCPD_ADDENDA ,    CE_CLI_SEGMENTO ,    CE_DISC_DOCRESPORFON ,    CE_DISC_DDJJAYFAM ,    CE_DISC_DDJJREGALO,     CE_DISC_DDJJ43774717 ,    CE_DISC_DDJJ5085  ,   CE_DISC_DDJJ52207  ,   CE_DISC_EXTRCTAEXTE   ,  CE_DISC_DOCPARENTESC,     CE_DISC_FCPROFORMA,     CE_OPE_SALDO ,    CE_CANAL_INGRESO,     CE_NROSOL_GO,     CE_FECHA_LIQ_OPE,     CE_DISC_CONTRATO,     CE_DISC_LETRA,     CE_DISC_SOL3978,     CE_DISC_SOL3979 ,    CE_DISC_SOL3980,     CE_DISC_SOL3981 ,    CE_DISC_SOL3982 ,    CE_DISC_SOL3983 ,    CE_TIPO_DISCREPANCIA ,    CE_DISC_SOLTRANSF ,    CE_DISC_COMA4662 ,    CE_DISC_Sol4982 ,    CE_DISC_S3909DEP,     CE_DISC_S3909C4359,     CE_DISC_DDJJDNR ,    CE_DISC_S3909D616,     CE_DISC_Sol3909 ,    CE_DISC_COMA4237 ,    CE_DISC_DDJJ4762A,     CE_DISC_DDJJ4762C ,    CE_DISC_COMA4860 ,    CE_DISC_CASOS447 ,    CE_DISC_sol3909D  ,   CE_DISC_SOL4981  ,   CE_COMA_5384  ,   CE_APORTE_CAPITAL ,    CE_CID_APLI_IMPO ,    CE_DISC_EXPO ,    CE_DISC_PRESTAMO ,    CE_CELULA  ,   CE_DISC_5264 ,    CE_DISC_DJAS ,    CE_CLI_OBSERVACION ,    IMAGEN_GO_ID ,    CE_TIMESTAMP_GO ,    CE_DISC_DOC_RESP  ,   Disc_com_A_5630  ,   CE_DISC_EXCEL  ,   CE_DISC_CONTRATOS  ,   DISC_COM_A_5441   ,  DISC_COM_A_5264
INTO #temp1
FROM THUBAN_INDEXES_AUX
WHERE (
    SELECT INDEX_ITEM_ID
    FROM THUBAN_INDEXES_AUX
    WHERE (SUBSTRING(INDEX_ITEM_ID, 1, 8)) =  CONVERT(char(10),getdate(),112)
)
```

> The error is "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context
>   where a condition is expected, near ')'."

Comment: What is the point of that subquery? You're selecting from the SAME table in the parent and sub queries, which is utterly pointless.

Comment: @mihai: don't format the fields. they're irrelevant to the problem, and hide the main problem by shoving it down a few gazillion lines.

Comment: Which RDMBS is this?

Comment: In my experience your error message means you have a syntax error. In this case it is that when you use a WHERE  clause you have to compare something to something. @NoDisplayName has the right fix but I wanted to explain what was actually wrong.

Comment: Also, you shoud not be using subqwueries ever until you gan much more sql knowldge. They are very easy to misuse and cause performance problems in a database.  Learn the basics of using the where clause and grouping and joins before you ever consider using a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your where doesn't make any sense. Use this `Where clause`

```
.....
INTO   #temp1
FROM   THUBAN_INDEXES_AUX
WHERE  Substring(INDEX_ITEM_ID, 1, 8) = CONVERT(CHAR(10), Getdate(), 112)
```